# Simplify unicode char to ascii

Tags: python, unicode, multilingual, transcription

I find `unicodedata` package to remove diacritics of latin letters like é→e or ü→u, as you can see:

```py
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'éü').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'eu'
```

But it seams limited because 1) he doesn’t seems able to explode ligatures likes `æ` into `ae`or `œ` into `oe`, and 2) he doesn’t seems to translate some other symbols to the most similar equivalent in ASCII, like `ı` (dotless *i*) to `i`.

```py
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'éüœıx').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'eux'
```

So, is it a package, or a way to simplify unicode characters to the most similar ones in ASCII by respecting the points (1) and (2) ?
And also it would be great if it translate non latin symbols to the most similar ones like `И` (cyrillic *i*) to `i` or `أ` (arabic Alif) to `a` .

---

#### Edits after @wjandrea’s questions

For the non-latin case, I know theire is many romanisation ways depending from language for each script, and also a same  language could be romanised in many ways (like `و` the arabic waw witch can be transcript `w` or `o`).

BTW, the goal isn’t to support subtilities of linguastic and translations systems or traditions, but just to avoid as much as possible a blank output.

Imagine if the input is a full cyrillic words like, for example `Все люди рождаются свободными`. So, the output of `unicodedata` will just give "". When it will be preferable to get at least something, no matter if it’s a correct transcription or not.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? I ask because the `u` string prefix has no effect in Python 3, and Python 2 is EOL, but also Unicode handling was much more difficult in it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Any text that you put through this process is going to get garbled. For example, French `montré` "shown" -> `montre` "wristwatch", Turkish `ılık` "warm" -> `ilik` "marrow". Regarding non-Latin symbols, that might be more difficult than you think because how to convert them depends on the language, not just the script; for example, for Ukrainian, Cyrillic `И` transliterates to `y`, not `i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string) Note: the question asks about accents only, but the answers mostly cover reduction of Unicode to plain ASCII.

Comment: @wjandrea I use python3

Comment: @wjandrea yes, I know that latin translitaration depend on languages. And sometimes in a unic language, theire is many possible transliteration standard. But I don’t search a full  perfect solution. Just someting to avoid getting someting instead of blank output when the given char is full of cyrillic symbols, as example.

Comment: Why not just output the Unicode text? Are you dealing with a system that only supports ASCII?

Comment: Use [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).

Comment: @wjandrea there are lots of cases that require this, for example filling names, addresses... in a foreign form, or unaccented string match (most modern browsers do that by default)

Comment: @wjandrea the usecase is the following one: A user give his full name correctly writing in any language, but an ascii ID is associate to his account, for url or any context requiring ascii script.

Comment: Is it necessary for the ID to be readable, or could you use a base64 encoding of utf-8 characters?

Comment: @fauve why don't just give separate ID and Name fields? That's what most websites that require an ASCII ID do. Or just use email as ID